# Chrome Extension - can I add a search field to the context menu?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I'm wondering if it's possible to customize the chrome context menu? Specifically I want to add a search field to narrow down the options in my context menu. Right now I have a lot of options that will popup in one of my sub-context menus and it would be helpful if at the top of the sub-context menu I could build in a filter/search functionality. Looking at the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) this doesn't seem possible. Wondering if anybody has attempted this?

Comment: There's nothing to attempt: only the types defined in the documentation are supported.

Comment: Consider this idea: add a single context menu command which runs a content script that inserts a DOM element structure (or an iframe) with your menus, filters, and stuff.

Comment: Ya I was considering something like that, have the context item open up a modal and then populate the modal with everything I need. I think it's a good workaround